# Applications of definite integrals of shell method

Tags: calculus

Use cylindrical shells to find the volume of the solid generated when the region bounded by the curves $y=x^2$, the $x-$axis and the lines $x=1$ and $x=2$ is revolved about the $y-$axis.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
\text{The volume $V$ is given by the integral below. Let $y = f(x) = x^2$.} \\[10pt]
V = \int_{1}^{2}2\pi xf(x)dx = \int_{1}^{2}2\pi x(x^2)dx = 2\pi\int_{1}^{2} x^3dx = \frac{15\pi}{2}
$

Comment: Figure of this question??

Comment: I don't have any figures of this exact question, but I do have a link to the method with the equation used. https://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Concepts%20and%20Contexts/upfiles/3c3-Volums-CylinShells_Stu%20.pdf